# How to update the FTP state in azure function

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cli

I wanted to update the FTP state in azure function app, the below setting with Az command..
But I am not getting complete information with this document

Any input will be helpful here

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/cli/azure/functionapp/config/appsettings?view=azure-cli-latest#az-functionapp-config-appsettings-set
```

[image]

Comment: you mean programatically? using ARM is one way

Comment: @MattDouhan Using "az functionapp config appsettings set" command.

Comment: @MattDouhan how to achieve this with ARM

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results***

I have one function app with **FTP state** as *All allowed* as below:

[image]

To **update** it to `FTPS only` state from Azure CLI, you can make use of below Az command:

```
az webapp config set --name <functionapp-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --ftps-state FtpsOnly
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I refreshed the page, FTP state is changed to **`FTPS only`** successfully like below:

[image]

If you want to change it to `Disabled` state, you can use below command:

```
az webapp config set --name <functionapp-name> --resource-group <resource-group-name> --ftps-state Disabled
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I refreshed the page, **FTP state** is changed to **`Disabled`** successfully like below:

[image]